# Create VPCPeeringConnection across AWS accounts via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Within AWS, I am trying to create a VPC peering connection between two VPC's in different accounts via CloudFormation.

I can create the peering connections manually via the UI, with the 4 fields:

```
Name
Local VPC

Target Account ID
Target VPC ID
```

It seems as if the [CLI also supports a target Account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-vpc-peering-connection.html).

The problem comes when trying to do this same thing via CloudFormation, using the [`AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcpeeringconnection.html) object, the problem being that this object seems to only support 3 fields, [Target Account not being one of them](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcpeeringconnection.html#d0e64519) -

```
PeerVpcId
VpcId
Tags
```

With my code resulting in

```
AttributeError: AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection object does not support attribute PeerVpcOwner
```

> How can I go about creating a VPCPeeringConnection to a VPC in another account via CloudFormation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

YES YOU CAN configure VPC peering with cloudformation between two AWS accounts.

> You can peer with a virtual private cloud (VPC) in another AWS account
>   by using AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection. This creates a networking
>   connection between two VPCs that enables you to route traffic between
>   them so they can communicate as if they were within the same network.
>   A VPC peering connection can help facilitate data access and data
>   transfer.
>
> To establish a VPC peering connection, you need to authorize two
>   separate AWS accounts within a single AWS CloudFormation stack.

Source: [Walkthrough: Peer with an Amazon VPC in Another AWS Account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/peer-with-vpc-in-another-account.html)

#### Step 1: Create a VPC and a Cross-Account Role

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Create a VPC and an assumable role for cross account VPC peering.",
  "Parameters": {
    "PeerRequesterAccountId": {
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "vpc": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.1.0.0/16",
        "EnableDnsSupport": false,
        "EnableDnsHostnames": false,
        "InstanceTenancy": "default"
      }
    },
    "peerRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Principal": {
                "AWS": {
                  "Ref": "PeerRequesterAccountId"
                }
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ],
              "Effect": "Allow"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "root",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": "ec2:AcceptVpcPeeringConnection",
                  "Resource": "*"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "VPCId": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "vpc"
      }
    },
    "RoleARN": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "peerRole",
          "Arn"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Step 2: Create a Template That Includes AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Create a VPC and a VPC Peering connection using the PeerRole to accept.",
  "Parameters": {
    "PeerVPCAccountId": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "PeerVPCId": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "PeerRoleArn": {
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "vpc": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.2.0.0/16",
        "EnableDnsSupport": false,
        "EnableDnsHostnames": false,
        "InstanceTenancy": "default"
      }
    },
    "vpcPeeringConnection": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "vpc"
        },
        "PeerVpcId": {
          "Ref": "PeerVPCId"
        },
        "PeerOwnerId": {
          "Ref": "PeerVPCAccountId"
        },
        "PeerRoleArn": {
          "Ref": "PeerRoleArn"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "VPCId": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "vpc"
      }
    },
    "VPCPeeringConnectionId": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "vpcPeeringConnection"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A quick question, how do we refer to another account's VPC and role automatically (without hard-coding them to ensure that we can replicate it across different stacks)?

Comment: Use something like ansible to query this information and then pass on the values as CloudFormation parameters.

Comment: How I ignore the accept of the vpc peering , because I want t o do it manually at peerer account without cross account role

Comment: Unfortunately kind of worthless, because both sides need to add routes to use the VPC peering connection. Thanks AWS! :)

Comment: The peering is just a connection, routing is always separate, even if you create a vpc, you can't create routes until you setup subnets. The dependency is not added by AWS but just the nature of networks.